# Application prevents installer from returning Exit Code

Tags: powershell, inno-setup

Got weird problem. I have installer, which works just fine. I'm launching it with PowerShell, something like

```
$p = 'Start-Process $path -Verb "RunAs" -PassThru -Wait'
$p = Invoke-Expression $p
```

and getting its exit code as `$p.ExitCode`
Usually it all works perfect. But I've added `ShellExec` in `CurStepChanged`, for `ssPostInstall` step, to launch additional executable after installation finish.

```
ShellExec('', ExpandConstant('{app}\DentalDesktopServerAgent.exe'), '', '', SW_HIDE, ewNoWait, ResultCode);
```

And with this, it does no longer return exit code. *This line is the only difference between installer with and without exit code*. And since PowerShell script is waiting for exit code, it simply hangs.

So, why does ShellExec impact exit code? Any ideas?

**Update:**
It seems, problem is not in ShellExec, but in launched application itself. Application itself is not supposed to be closed (it is helper application for main installed application). I've tried to move it to [Run], and it seems, that application does not return exit code (thats obvious). But I'm not sure, that this causes installer to not return its own exit code, since even after moving launching of application to bat file, when bat file returns exit code right after application was started, installer still does not return exit code, although all its [Run] entry do.

**Update:**
Additional info incoming. Logged result code of Exec, which launches application. Code is 259, which means "application still in progress". Is it possible, that it impacts result code of installer?

Comment: Changing from `ShellExec` to `Exec` did completely nothing.

Comment: It seems your installer just hangs on the start of DentalDesktopServerAgent.exe and never returns to your script..

Comment: @MartinMaat Installer actually successfully closes - I can't find it in processes after some time. Also, I was sure that ewNoWait flag exists for launching applications and going on after that.

Comment: Replacing `Exec` with entry in `[Run]` section also has no result. Is there any alternative to launch additional exe (not related to installer)?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I have log already. How should it actually end? In my logs, last entry is "Deinitializing Setup".

Comment: Anyway, it is for Exec method. I will move execution to Run section, to see, what log will say. If no luck with finding reason, will try to add bat file, which will start application.

Comment: Okay, in log, application is executed, but no Exit Code is provided by it (which is obvious since application never closes). Installer stilll continues its actions, not waiting for exit code, and closes after installation is finished. Could it be, that Run entry without exit code prohibits installer to return its own exit code?

Comment: 1) The last log entry should be *"Log closed."*. The *"Deinitializing Setup."* is just before that. 2) Do you have `DeinitializeSetup` event function in your script? It is called in between the *"Deinitializing Setup."* and the *"Log closed."* 3) Can you see the installer process in the Task Manager after the installer seemingly finishes?

Comment: It's not possible that a process does not return exit code. Process always returns some exit code. The problem probably is that the process does not exit.

Comment: 1. Well, that's weird. 2. I'm not overloading this event. 3. No installer in Task Manager after installation (that was first thing i've checked).

Comment: Application is not supposed to exit. It is additional application to one which is installed.

Comment: I will try option with intermediate file, which will start agent instead of installer.

Comment: Changed to bat file, running my ServerAgent with `start` command, it does return exit code, but installer still doesn't. Now that's completely weird.

Comment: If you run DentalDesktopServerAgent from the command line, does it give you any clues? How about "DentalDesktopServerAgent /?" ? I guess asking the developer of DentalDesktopServerAgent is out of the question... Could DentalDesktopServerAgent be Windows service application? If so you could try  "DentalDesktopServerAgent /install".

Comment: Actually, I'm developer of DentalDesktopServerAgent, but it is simple WinForms tray application, and I have no idea, how and why does it impact installer. It is WCF application, but it is not Service itself, it communicates with service, which is also installed with installer, and which never caused me any problems of that sort.

Comment: So, if you replace DentalDesktopServerAgent with Notepad, your installer will just fire a Notepad instance and finish nicely with the expected exit code?

Comment: @MartinMaat Nope, same result with Notepad. It seems, Inno Setup doesn't like, when applications are started within, and not closed. Probably bug.

Comment: How about not using ShellExec ? You don't need it for executable files  http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection  Since your app is a tray app there should be nothing to hide anyway. Whatever special behavior you need you can program into your trayapp, passing it a parameter to get the behavior if needed. And if that doesn't work, what happens if you put the launch in a different section (not [run])?

Comment: It seems, installer DOES return exit code, once I close launched application... Mb, it's problem of PowerShell, not Inno Setup?

Comment: @Martin Maat Doesn't it require checkbox for starting?

Comment: Do you need a checkbox, do you want the user to decide? If so, create a task: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=taskssection

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98978/discussion-between-martin-maat-and-lentinant).

Comment: If you are able to reproduce the problem with Notepad, create a small Inno Setup script that reproduces the problem with Notepad and append it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I did not read your question very well yesterday. It seems it is the Invoke-Expression that is giving you trouble. Try launching your installer the normal way (by just stating its path as in a batch file) and then check PowerShell variable $LastExitCode.

I assume you know what exit codes to compare to:
http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupexitcodes